# Evaluate same logic condition on multiple columns of DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains several measurements (time-series). Amongst these measurements, some come from similar pieces of equipment (in this case, 6 pumps)
This is a sample of my data:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = {'pump1': [20,20],'pump2': [21,30],'pump3': [24,38],'pump4': [23,30],'pump5': [22,30],'pump6': [2,36], 'current':[10,200], 'flow': [50,50]})
```

```
    pump1  pump2  pump3  pump4  pump5  pump6  current  flow
0      20     21     24     23     22      2       10    50
1      20     30     38     30     30     36      200    50
```

I am trying to evaluate if all 6 pumps meet the ***same*** criteria. That is,whether the value of every pump on the row is less than 25. 
In this case, row 0 would return `True`, and row 1 would return `False`

I could write:

```
df["idle"] = (df["pump1"]<25) & (df["pump2"]<25) & (df["pump3"]<25) & (df["pump4"]<25) & (df["pump5"]<25) & (df["pump6"]<25)
```

But it's pretty ugly! Is there a better way to write this?

I thought I could use something like `.all()` and write the condition `<25` only once... but I don't know where to start!

Comment: df['idle'] = (df<25).all(axis=1) ?

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you! Henry's answer does the column filtering which I also needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df["result"] = (df.filter(like="pump",axis=1)<25).all(1)

print (df)

   pump1  pump2  pump3  pump4  pump5  pump6  current  flow  result
0     20     21     24     23     22      2       10    50    True
1     20     30     38     30     30     36      200    50   False
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't even thought of using the "like" so I don;t have to specify one-by-one all my column names!

Comment: I added link to the documentation. With `filter` you can also select columns by regex pattern.